How to add a simple extra shader effect in Unity's URP in code
I would like to be able to add certain simple graphical effects to objects in my game. For example, I want dead enemies to fade out, I want enemies that get hit to flash white, all easy stuff.
So far I've implemented these things by simply setting the color of the GameObject (GetComponent().material.color.a) but it occcured to me that if I want to do this properly, in a way that plays nice with all possible textures, and especially when I combine multiple effects (what if the color is set by 3 scripts, one trying to make it fade, one trying to make it flash and one trying to give it an outline) I should probably write a shader instead.
I've worked with shaders outside of Unity (I've written some simple stuff for projects using vanilla C++ with OpenGL and GLFW) so I thought I'd just write my own shader. Now, it seems that things like the 'Standard Surface Shader' (In a project window, right click -> Create -> Shader -> Standard Surface Shader) doesn't work anymore because of the URP. I'm rather new to this but it seems like everyone is using Shader Graphs, and out of the box, these do seem to work.
However, I would prefer just to write (shader) code, but even getting a result as good as the template that you get when creating a new Shader Graph seems rather difficult; I wonder if I'm overlooking some options here. Basically I just want to add a few small things to the standard behavior of materials, simple stuff like color = color * (1-param) + color_white * param, or color.a = param. I cannot really find the place to put this code, so to speak.
